# Retrieve tweets from own twitter account wall

Tags: android, twitter, tweets

I want to retrieve tweets from my twitter account wall.

After retrieving the tweets from wall of my own twitter account wall i want to show those tweets in a list.

Showing in a list is not a problem. But i am unable to retrieve tweets from my own twitter account wall. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of helpful links

https://dev.twitter.com/docs

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

You would place a GET request against the API with parameters based on your needs.

The second page gives you specific syntax on how to find tweets.

For example:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40twitterapi

This finds any tweets mentioning @twitterapi. Replacing it with q=from:twitterapi would find any tweets from @twitterapi. Substitute your username, and don't forget to encode the URL string.

Comment: This is the most common way I know of. But posted the API links in case you need something different.

Comment: I am not getting list of tweets from my own twitter account.

Comment: If you go to  http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:debam_13  in a normal browser window, you'll see the JSON code that is returned. Looking over it "Hello World!!! http://t.co/zoUKfWjB" looks like your most recent post.  So the process is to make a GET Request to that address (remember to URL encode) and then process the JSON returned.  You may need to check the other options for the searches if you want to include older tweets.

Comment: Yes its absolutely perfect. But what i am looking for is a list of tweets from my twitter wall, not only the latest tweet.Do you have any idea?

Comment: The search functionality may disregard older tweets. There are other API for getting all kinds of information from twitter in the first link posted.

Comment: See http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40twitterapi%20-via . This is giving list of tweets.But i am not getting my own list of tweets.

Comment: search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:debam_13

Comment: But there is something strange. I am getting a list from debam_13 , but when i increase the number of tweets after a certain number. Before that the same link was not giving any list. Thus i am not getting this list from username debarati13. Have you any idea?

Comment: okay got it.This link gives you only the latest rather today's tweets what you have posted. Not before that. Do you have any idea of that?